# iText#: Wrong NamespaceUri for ZUGFeRD

Tags: java, pdf, itext, zugferd

After looking in my ZUGFeRD-PDF's metadata, I found out that iText# defined the wrong/old namespaceURI for ZUGFeRD in the PdfAXmpWriter.

The namspaceUri for `zf` is `urn:ferd:pdfa:CrossIndustryDocument:invoice:1p0#`which is correctly defined in the regular iText (for Java), but in iText# is defined `urn:ferd:pdfa:invoice:1p0#`

https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/master/pdfa/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/xml/xmp/PdfAXmpWriter.java

https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/extras/itextsharp.pdfa/iTextSharp/text/xml/xmp/PdfAXmpWriter.cs

Could you check this?

Comment: Thanks. This actually isn't a question, but a bug report. I'll post it on our internal tracker.

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't know where to post it. For next time: Where do I have to open a ticket?

Comment: Only customers can create a ticket. That's why I created one for you.

Comment: Do I have a chance to change the namespaceURI by iText? I tried replacing the "PdfAXmpWriter.zugferdSchemaNS" through the correct namespaceURI, but an error occurs that says "Unregistered schema namespace URI".

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. The best way to fix the problem is to correct the iText or iTextSharp code. Is that what you tried? Is this what causes the error?

Comment: Well that would have been an option, but I tried this way:
`copy.XmpWriter.SetProperty("urn:ferd:pdfa:CrossIndustryDocument:invoice:1p0#", PdfAXmpWriter.zugferdDocumentFileName, "ZUGFeRD-invoice.xml");`

`copy` is an instance of PdfCopy.

Comment: I know, but that's a "hack" and even if it works, it doesn't help other people with the same problem. It's better to remove the root cause of the problem. I see that the ticket was accepted and that it will be taken care of in the next sprint.

Comment: I was about to do that to solve this for me so far (hotfix) and wait for the next release. How shall **I** remove the root cause?^^